# Can't get ASMock to Dipatch Events

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, actionscript, mocking, asmock

I can't find my mistake, hope someone can help me out.
I am trying to unit test my actionscript application using ASMock.
I want to perform an asynchron test, but I don't get my mocked function to dispatch.
this is what I did:

```
[Test(async,timeout="5000")]
public function testFailedIDResponse() : void {
  var mockRepository : MockRepository = new MockRepository();
```

// Record

```
var oMock:ConnectionProcessor  = ConnectionProcessor(mockRepository.createStub(ConnectionProcessor));
oMock.addEventListener("ConnectionProcessor.LOGICALERROR", Async.asyncHandler(this, onWrongID, 5000)); 
SetupResult.forCall(oMock.logigalErrorCode).returnValue("NOT_FOUND");
SetupResult.forEventDispatcher(oMock);
SetupResult.forCall(oMock.load()).dispatchEvent(new Event("ConnectionProcessor.LOGICALERROR"));
mockRepository.replayAll();
oMock.load();
```

but the event never arrives at my onWrongID handler.
where is my error?
thanks a lot guys!

Comment: FYI, the call to `forEventDispatcher` is not required as `createStub` defaults to doing that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your call to `addEventListener` until after `replayAll`. As it stands, it's just recording your call to `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the dispatchEvent-method from your mocked object.

e.g.

```
oMock.dispatchEvent(new Event("ConnectionProcessor.LOGICALERROR"));
```

Then your class/method/... under test will be able to handle the event.

or if you expect the load method to be called in somewhere before you could work with

```
Expect.call(oMock.load()).dispatchEvent(new Event("ConnectionProcessor.LOGICALERROR"));
```

hope that helped.
br,